# MSFT Access - is it possible to use data in a spreadsheet to bulk update multiple existing records in Access?

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to bulk upload data into fields in existing records in Access? For example, I have a table containing records of customer data. I have an excel spreadsheet containing these same customers' employers. I need a way to bulk update the employer field for the existing customer records in Access. How can I accomplish this without individually copying and pasting each employer into each existing customer record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the "External Data" feature to link or import the Excel sheet into Access
2. Create a query that joins the customer table with the linked customer sheet (assuming there is a key column that you can use for the JOIN)
3. Once this works, change the query to an UPDATE query and update the Access column from the Excel column.

Afterthought: the linked Excel sheet and hence the UPDATE query may be read-only in Access, in this case you need to use "Import" instead of "Link", so you can join two Access tables.

Comment: Thank you! This worked :)